# Jquery validates one row out of many rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am working in one inventory project I use bootsrap modal for inserting and updating records the problem that I am facing is that when I am editing the record the jquery validation only applied on first row not on any other row can any one help me in this matter.

**index page is like below**

```
<tbody>
  @foreach ($suppliers as $key => $supplier)
    <tr class="odd">
      <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
      <td>{{ $supplier->name }}</td>
      <td>{{ $supplier->mobile_no }}</td>
      <td>{{ $supplier->email }}</td>
      <td>{{ $supplier->address }}</td>
      <td>
          <a href="#edit{{ $supplier->id }}" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="fas fa-edit"                                                 title="Edit Data" style=" margin-right:20px">
         </a>
      @include('backend.supplier.editSupplier')
   </td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Modal is like below**

```
<div class="modal fade editModal" id="edit{{ $supplier->id }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Edit Supplier</h5>
                  <button type="button" class=" btn btn-danger btn btn-sm close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                      aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
              </div>
              <form id="editForm" method="POST" action="{{ route('supplier.update', $supplier->id) }}"
                  class="needs-validation" novalidate>
                  @csrf
                  @method('PUT')
                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <!-- name -->
                      <div class="col-md-12 ">
                          <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                               <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Supplier Name"
                                  id="name" name="name1" value="{{ $supplier->name }}">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- mobile number -->
                      <div class="col-md-12 ">
                          <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                              <input class="form-control " type="text" autocomplete="mobile_no"
                                  placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobile_no" name="mobile_no1"
                                  value="{{ $supplier->mobile_no }}">

                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <!-- email -->
                      <div class="col-md-12 ">
                          <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                              <input class="form-control " type="email_address" placeholder="Email" id="email_address"
                                  name="email_address1" value="{{ $supplier->email }}">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-md-12 ">
                          <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                              <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="address" placeholder="Address"
                                  id="address" name="address1" value="{{ $supplier->address }}">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                          onclick="resetForm()">No</button>
                      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Supplier</button>
                  </div>
              </form>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Jquery code is like below**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#editForm').validate({
                rules: {
                    name1: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    mobile_no1: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    address1: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                    email_address1: {
                        required: true,
                    },
                },
                messages: {
                    name1: {
                        required: 'Please Enter Supplier Name',
                    },
                    mobile_no1: {
                        required: 'Please Enter Supplier mobile number',
                    },
                    address1: {
                        required: 'Please Enter Supplier address',
                    },
                    email_address1: {
                        required: 'Please Enter Supplier email',
                    },
                },
                errorElement: 'span',
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
                    element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
                },
                highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
                },
            });

        });
     
      function resetForm() {
          $("#editForm").trigger("reset");

          var validator = $("#editForm").validate();
          validator.resetForm();
      }
  </script>
```

Comment: Are you including the modal with this code? `@include('backend.supplier.editSupplier')`  IF this is true, you are producing invalid HTML after the first row.

Comment: yes I did include the modal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a VERY verbose example but here I take a rendered table and remove the form from that.  This avoids duplication of the id's on the form and also gives you smaller HTML and the ability to use the same form over in every row and on and "add" action.

I then trigger the edit with the edit link/button; it saves by submit of the form but you could alter that to post the data using ajax or something also.

I did not venture into the "add" but you could put a button on the screen for that also; stick the id or whatever you need in the "action" to save the NEW item in that part.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#editForm').validate({
    rules: {
      name1: {
        required: true,
      },
      mobile_no1: {
        required: true,
      },
      address1: {
        required: true,
      },
      email_address1: {
        required: true,
      }
    },
    messages: {
      name1: {
        required: 'Please Enter Supplier Name',
      },
      mobile_no1: {
        required: 'Please Enter Supplier mobile number',
      },
      address1: {
        required: 'Please Enter Supplier address',
      },
      email_address1: {
        required: 'Please Enter Supplier email',
      }
    },
    errorElement: 'span',
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
      error.addClass('invalid-feedback');
      element.closest('.form-group').append(error);
    },
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).addClass('is-invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
      $(element).removeClass('is-invalid');
    }
  });

  $('#my-great-suppliers').on('click', '.edit-link', function(event) {
    //event.preventDefault().preventPropagation();
    console.log('set up edit');
    const trow = $(this).closest('.supplier-row');
    console.log("Row:", trow.index(), trow.length);
    const modal = $('#edit-modal-container').find('.edit-modal-child');
    const modalForm = modal.find('#editForm');
    const rowEdits = trow.find('.edit-me');
    let supplierid = $(this).data("supplierid");
    let name = rowEdits.filter('[data-suppliername]').data("suppliername");
    let email = rowEdits.filter('[data-email]').data("email");
    let mobile = rowEdits.filter('[data-mobile]').data("mobile");
    let address = rowEdits.filter('[data-address]').data("address");
    console.log(supplierid, name, trow.length);
    modalForm.find('#name').val(name);
    modalForm.find('#email_address').val(email);
    modalForm.find('#address').val(address);
    modalForm.find('#mobile_no').val(mobile);
    let actionV = modalForm.attr("action");
    console.log(actionV);
    // update the form action with the id
    modalForm.attr("action", actionV + supplierid);
    //  modal.show();
  });
  $('.submit-button').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const modalForm = $('#editForm');
    console.log("trying to save");
    // now do what you need to validate
    if (modalForm.valid()) {
      // add your extra logic here to execute only when element is valid
      console.log('It is valid');
      let savedata = {
        name: modalForm.find('#name').val(),
        email: modalForm.find('#email_address').val(),
        address: modalForm.find('#address').val(),
        mobile: modalForm.find('#mobile_no').val()
      };
      console.log("Saving:", savedata, 'To:', modalForm.attr("action"));
      //now do what you want to save the form
      // since we updated the action when edit started we have the id in there
      //  modalForm.submit()
    }
  });
});

function resetForm() {
  $("#editForm").trigger("reset");
  let validator = $("#editForm").validate();
  validator.resetForm();
}
```

```css
.edit-link {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

.edit-modal-container {}

.cheers {
  border: solid 1px green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.2.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-MV7K8+y+gLIBoVD59lQIYicR65iaqukzvf/nwasF0nqhPay5w/9lJmVM2hMDcnK1OnMGCdVK+iQrJ7lzPJQd1w==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js" integrity="sha512-rstIgDs0xPgmG6RX1Aba4KV5cWJbAMcvRCVmglpam9SoHZiUCyQVDdH2LPlxoHtrv17XWblE/V/PP+Tr04hbtA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<table id="my-great-suppliers" class="my-great-suppliers-container">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="supplier-row odd">
      <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">$key1</td>
      <td class='edit-me' data-suppliername="Dirt supplier">Dirt supplier</td>
      <td class="edit-me" data-mobile="123-123-1234">123-123-1234</td>
      <td class="edit-me" data-email="happydays@example.com">happydays@example.com</td>
      <td class="edit-me" data-address="1234 Main St">1234 Main St</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" data-supplierid="supplier-1" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="edit-link fas fa-edit" title="Edit Data" data-bs-target="#supplier-modal">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="supplier-row odd">
      <td class="sorting_1 dtr-control">$key2</td>
      <td class='edit-me' data-suppliername="Rock supplier">Rock supplier</td>
      <td class='edit-me' data-mobile="321-123-4321">321-123-4321</td>
      <td class='edit-me' data-email="biggerrocks@example.com">biggerrocks@example.com</td>
      <td class='edit-me' data-address="12 Granite Lane">12 Granite Lane</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" data-supplierid="supplier-2" data-bs-toggle="modal" class="edit-link fas fa-edit" data-bs-target="#supplier-modal" title="Edit Data">
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<div id="edit-modal-container" class="edit-modal-container">
  <div id='supplier-modal' class="edit-modal-child modal fade editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Edit Supplier</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn btn-sm close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                  </button>
        </div>
        <form id="editForm" method="POST" action="/route/supplierupdate/" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="name" placeholder="Supplier Name" id="name" name="name1" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                <input class="form-control " type="text" autocomplete="mobile_no" placeholder="Mobile Number" id="mobile_no" name="mobile_no1" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                <input class="form-control " type="email_address" placeholder="Email" id="email_address" name="email_address1" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 ">
              <div class="mb-3 position-relative form-group">
                <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="address" placeholder="Address" id="address" name="address1" value="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal" onclick="resetForm()">No</button>
            <button type="submit" class="submit-button btn btn-primary">Add Supplier</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you try to inspect the modal on each row. the input will have the same name eg. name1, mobile_no1, etc.

Jquery will validate the first input element with that name.

1. You can either move the modal and Jquery function each with their own unique id inside foreach. may use $supplier->id

Or

2. Im guessing the modal already inside the foreach since it have the unique id. Update eqch input to include the unique id(`name="mobile_no1<?php $supplier-id ?>"`) Then, update the jquery function to accept id identifier($supplier->id) so it can fetch the unique input element